# Setting number of shuffle partitions per shuffle in the same Spark job

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way, within the *same* Spark application or even the same job, to specify a different number of shuffle partitions for each shuffle, rather than a global number of shuffle partitions that applies for all?

In other words, can

```
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions
```

be set dynamically to a different value for each DataFrame transformation that involves shuffling?

This is for a scenario in which a job is a large DAG, and some shuffle outputs might be small and others very large.

Thanks!

Comment: try manually doing `df.repartition(n_partition)` after each shuffle operation?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does repartition() not create an additional shuffling? My focus here is performance.

Comment: Not sure, I was thinking that the query planner might interpret that you want to change the number of partitions after shuffle... maybe you can check how the query plan looks like if you put `.repartition`

Comment: That's a very good point -- from what I see here, it does not optimize: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-performance-tuning-groupBy-aggregation.html but now I notice repartition() is called before the shuffling. So there is still a chance the optimizer might kick in if it's right after the shuffling.

Comment: I think the only way to achieve what you are asking for is to manually shuffle data frames beforehand. In this way, Spark will detect that the data frames have been already aligned and won't do another shuffle. For example, you rewrite `df1.join(df2, "id")` to `df1.repartition(10, df1("id")).join(df2.repartition(10, df2("id")), "id")`. In both of the cases, the data is shuffled only once and the only difference is the number of partitions in the result data frame. The former will bring `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` partitions, the latter - 10.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

Issue command `sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "nnn")` before the JOIN or Aggregation. Has no effect on broadcast hash join aspect of a query though.

Try and see.